# How to find the product and sum of digits in a big number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, I have:

$2^{2016}*5^{2018}$. How can I find the product of the nonzero digits?

Similarly I have $5^{2016}*2^{2018}$, how can I find the sum of the digits?

Comment: remember that $5\times2=10$.

Comment: so it would be $10^{2016*2018}$ for the product and $2016+2018$ for the sum?

Comment: No, $2^{2016}\cdot 5^{2018}=5^2 \cdot (2 \cdot 5)^{2016}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $$2^{2016}\cdot 5^{2018}=(2\cdot5)^{2016}\cdot 5^{2}=10^{2016}\cdot 25=25\underbrace{000\ldots00}_{2016\text{ zeroes}}$$ The product is thus $2\cdot 5=10$.

The second case can be solved similarly: $$5^{2016}\cdot2^{2018}=\ldots=4\underbrace{000\ldots00}_{2016\text{ zeroes}}$$ The sum is, hence, $4$.